# Python - Subtracting elements in lists of tuples

Tags: list, python-3.x, numpy

I have two lists of tuples.

```
x = [(A1, B1, C1), (A2, B2, C2),...(AN, BN, CN)]
```

and

```
y = [(A1_, B1_, C1_), (A2_, B2_, C2_),...(AN_, BN_, CN_)]
```

I want to do the following things:

1. Obtain a new list`[(A1, B1, C1 - C1_), (A2, B2, C2 -
   C2_),...(AN, BN, CN - CN_)]`
2. And from there, create a list that
   solely consists of [C1 - C1_, C2 - C2_,...]

I'd venture to say that something in Numpy would allow me to do this, but I still have not dug up how to just do an operation on one element in a tuple, so I would appreciate any possible help. 
Thanks.

Comment: Learn how to use [list comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and the [`zip`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) function.

Comment: And you don't have a list of lists, but a list of tuples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you start with `x` and `y` being a list of tuples, then it is easy to convert them to 2D NumPy arrays:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([(1,2,3), (4,5,6), (7,8,9)])
y = np.array([(10,20,30), (40,50,60), (70,80,90)])
```

Then to create an *array* similar to

```
[(A1, B1, C1 - C1_), (A2, B2, C2 - C2_),...(AN, BN, CN - CN_)]
```

you could do this:

```
z = x[:]           # make a copy of array x
z[:,2] -= y[:,2]   # subtract the 3rd column of y from z

print(z)
```

yields

```
[[  1   2 -27]
 [  4   5 -54]
 [  7   8 -81]]
```

and to get

```
[C1 - C1_, C2 - C2_,...]
```

you could either use `z[:, 2]` or obtain it directly from `x` and `y` using `x[:, 2] - y[:, 2]`:

```
[-27 -54 -81]
```

---

I might be misunderstanding your question, but when you say "*I still have not dug up how to just do an operation on one element in a tuple*" it makes me think you might be storing tuples in a NumPy array. If that's true, then I'd urge you to reconsider the way you are using NumPy:

You see, when you use `dtype=object` to store Python objects in a NumPy array (such as a tuple), then all operations done on these objects ultimately involve calls to Python functions, rather than the faster C/Fortran compiled functions that NumPy normally calls.

Thus, while you may enjoy NumPy syntax for selecting items in the array, you do not gain any speed advantage over plain Python objects. In fact, it can be slower than using plain Python objects (such as a list of tuples).

For this reason, I would recommend avoiding storing Python objects in  NumPy arrays whenever possible, and especially when those objects are numerical, since NumPy's native numeric dtypes serve much better.

Instead of storing 3-tuples in an array, it would be better to add an extra dimension (a so-called "axis") to the NumPy array and store the 3 components along this axis.

Once you do that, the numerical calculation you contemplate is a piece of cake. It could be done with something like:

```
x[:,2]-y[:,2]
```

Answer (score 1):

Without numpy:

```
>>> x = [(1,2,3), (4,5,6), (7,8,9)]
>>> y = [(10,20,30), (40,50,60), (70,80,90)]
>>> [ (a[0], a[1], a[2] - b[2]) for a, b in zip(x, y) ]
[(1, 2, -27), (4, 5, -54), (7, 8, -81)]
>>> [ a[2] - b[2] for a, b in zip(x, y) ]
[-27, -54, -81]
```